# container gets default port

Tags: port-forwarding, docker, services

i am new with containers and dockers. I just pulled centos:latest image and installed httpd and commited to image. When i run my image as a container it's gets default port 80/tcp, 8080/tcp. i haven't done any configuration yet i just installed httpd on centos image that's all.
here is docker ps

`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS          PORTS         NAMES`

docker run -d -ti centos

`3d38df6f78d0   centos        "/bin/bash"  32 minutes ago     Up 32 minutes                  zen_bohr`

docker run -d -ti guidebook:v2

`65b0487542a7   guidebook:v2   "/sbin/init"   30 min ago       Up 30 min     80/tcp, 8080/tcp   cool`
thanks.

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You state that your container gets "default" ports, so 80/tcp and 8080/tcp. Is that unwanted? Is that wanted? What do you need?